# Update mobile number during login if MFA is required in cognito and only sms mfa is allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I have a scenario where the users can only have SMS MFA.
I would like to allow the user to add their mobile number during login if they don't have a mobile number already if the user pool has MFA required, currently I don't find a way to do that.
I am trying to use updateUserAttributes call but I get user is not authenticated error.

I see this is being done in the hosted UI not sure how to replicate it with amplify/cognito client libraries.